# c# Facebook SDK, get token to write to my Page Wall

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to write from my site to my Facebook page.

I am using this c# SDK:     [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk)

I found the Facebook documentation : [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

To make this operations, i need to get a token before, like documented here (Page login section)  [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

If i try to type the url in the browser, like in the example and using my application data, the token will be give me back in the URL.

This is the sample url that will return my token in the url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&
 response_type=token
```

My question is: i'm using asp.net MVC, how can i call this url and get the returned token (from url); WebResponse method does not let me to have the returned url.

which class  and method should i use into my controller?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved bypassing this step.

I manually get the token for the admininistrator of the page and after i can obtain the token of every page administrated by the user.

Then i store it into web.config (application settings).
With this token i can publish to my wall from my server when i want.

[See FB Page Section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login)