# How to get NON-EXPIRING Page Login token with Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I have exactly the same problem as Marco here: [c# Facebook SDK, get token to write to my Page Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700847/c-facebook-sdk-get-token-to-write-to-my-page-wall) , got to the same point as Marco (obtaining token manually and storing in web.config.

Problem I have is that this token is set to expire, so it cannot be really used as config value in my web application.

Is there a way in Facebook c# SDK to obtain this type of token?

Please note that as a page admin, I've already granted my FCBK app `manage_pages` permission (which does not seem to expire) so there should not be any human interaction necessary when obtaining this type of token.

Thanks, Antonin

**EDIT**

seems like running this request: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<URI>&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access&response_type=token` might be what I'm looking for, non-expiring access token. Pay special attention to values for `scope` parameter, especially `offline_access`.

Comment: yes you're right! offline_access gives you possibility to generate non-expiring access token

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had read somewhere that the page access tokens were temporary even when asking for offline_access.  But that's really not an issue because you can use the user's permanent token to call `me/accounts` to get the list of apps and grab a token from there.

Comment: The only note to this: it will not be `me` in most cases since using it assumes user is active...